# C2440 Can't transform int to int &

Tags: c++

I got some trouble with my code. I think I missed some pointer, but can't find it.

Here is my code for class:

```
template <class T, class U>
class KeyValue

{
private:
    T _key;
    U _value;
public:


    KeyValue();
    KeyValue(T key, U value)
    {
        this->_key = key;
        this->_value = value
    };
    T GetKey() { return this->_key; }
    U GetValue() { return this->_value; }

};
```

And the error occurs in:

```
template<class T, class U>
inline U & SparseArray<T, U>::operator[](T key)
{
    for (std::list<KeyValue<T, U>>::iterator it = list->begin(); it != list->end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->GetKey() == key)
        {
            return it->GetValue();
        }
    }

    return (list->insert(list->begin(), KeyValue<T, U>(key, U())))->GetValue();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]. What you've described here isn't enough for any user to recreate your issue and thus diagnose it.

Comment: `inline U & ` is what your member claims to return, but `obj->GetValue()` is what it actually returns, which is `U GetValue()` in the actual implementation. An rvalue. An `U` is not an `U&`.

Answer (score 2):

`GetValue()` returns by value which means it gives you a *prvalue*.  *prvalue* is a temporary object that goes out of scope at the end of the full expression.  Because of this you are not allowed to bind a *lvalue reference* to it which is what your return type (`U &`) is.

If you want to return a reference to the underlying `_key` then `GetValue()` needs to return a *lvalue reference* like

```
T& GetKey() { return this->_key; }
```